# A specific query return a parse error when importing into phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql

i have been trying to run a bunch of queries at once by importing my query file into phpmyadmin..but this very specific query returns a parse error message..but when i try to run this query separately it works..can any1 plis point out the problem
this is the query that has parse error

```
SELECT company.comp_code, comp_name, op_outer.opening_description, op_outer.opening_available, op_outer.qual_code, candidate.cand_num, cand_lname, education.qual_code,
    (
    SELECT COUNT(i_inner.cand_num) 
    FROM placement i_inner
    WHERE i_inner.opening_num=op_outer.opening_num
    GROUP BY cand_num
    )AS 'Total Placements'
FROM opening op_outer
LEFT JOIN company ON company.comp_code=op_outer.comp_code
LEFT JOIN placement ON placement.opening_num=op_outer.opening_num
LEFT JOIN candidate ON candidate.cand_num=placement.cand_num
LEFT JOIN education ON education.qual_code=op_outer.qual_code
WHERE placement.cand_num IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: this query does not seem to have any syntax error and you say it runs if you run it separately. So the problme seems to be the bunch of queries maybe they are not separated correctly  (no spacing or delimiters)

Comment: Thanks..i was missing the delimiters and putting it in the wrong place

Comment: Please share the full and exact error message

Comment: i corrected it..actuallly i didnt put the delimiter